# Is Magento compatible with PHP 5.5?

Tags: php, magento, lamp

[This link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements) says that Magento is compatible with PHP 5.2.13 - 5.3.24, but when you run the PHP script to check server requirements, it says that is okay to run on 5.4 and even 5.5. But I've seen some issues with 5.4 over the internet.

So the question is: with [PHP 5.3 reaching its End of Life](http://php.net/archive/2013.php#id2013-07-11-1), is it possible to run Magento on PHP 5.5 and have a server with a PHP version that lasts longer?

Comment: Please contact the vendor of the software for your support options. Most users (if not all) here on this website are not associated with the vendor and can not give you any statements about assured PHP version and configuration compatibility. As I assume you know that already, I also assume that you ask this question merely just like "out of interest" here. Please direct it into the official channels so that you can answer here providing references to official sources.

Comment: This question would be more than welcome over at the Magento Stack Exchange.  http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, at least large parts of the code (as for any PHP 5.3 application). And as the source is available and rights to modify it are given to every user, for the parts of the code that is not compatible it is possible to remove any incompatibilities making it completely compatible with PHP 5.5.

If you need a more authorative statement, you need to contact the support, here is the sales funnel page: [Magento Support Overview](http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/overview).

Comment: It is not fully compatible. I have found just now, that it crashes with fatal error, while printing invoice PDF on PHP 5.5.5. This is because of incompatible changes in PHP 5.4 — constructors must have same signature as their abstract declaration.